# How to change language of google lightouse report

Tags: node.js, internationalization, lighthouse

It's possible to change language of Google Lighthouse CLI or with node script ?

I found a lot of i18n files in the source code. But, the json report goes out in english.

Thanks

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Solved with --locale option

```
lighthouse --locale fr https://www.chromestatus.com/features --view
```

Same value in node.

Answer (score -2):

If you only need a few Lighthouse report in english you can also use https://web.dev/measure/ and click on "View Report" this report is in english and get get exported in the usual way.